# What's a good way to receive donations?

Tags: donation

We're a Foundation with board members across various countries. We have some difficulty setting up a bank account. It's definitely easier to create a Bitcoin wallet, but we want more than that.

Here are some conditions:

- We want to keep track and control funds without too much overhead.
- We want unique addresses for each donation, so a e.g. multisig electrum wallet wouldn't be ideal.
- We don't mind relying on a 3rd party service.
- We don't have a bank account yet (so BitPay might not work for us).

What would be a good solution for us?

Comment: You don't need a bank account to accept Bitcoin with [Coinbase](https://beta.coinbase.com/join/isidore).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Coinbase.com has merchant tools](https://www.coinbase.com/merchant_tools) that allow non-profits et al. to accept donations.